# Territory Management Account assignment working in sandbox, but not in production

Tags: territory-management

I noticed that our org had some Accounts that had not been assigned to a territory, due to problems with the addresses. I corrected the problems, but the Accounts still did not get assigned.

I made the same changes in our partial copy sandbox and I saw that the Accounts were instantaneously assigned to a territory. The territory configuration is identical on sandbox and in production, so I don't understand why it's working in one place, but not the other.

There is a difference with respect to duplicate management: this is turned on, in production, but cannot be turned on in our sandbox. Does that affect territory management? I couldn't imagine.

The rules on when exactly Account assignment is run are subtle. For example, there is the option of making it optional on an Account page. But our org does not display that option on the Account page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it turned out to be exactly the option of making Territory Management Account assignment optional on an Account page. You can find this by editing the Account page layout, then click Layout Properties.

It has a property called "Evaluate this account against territory rules on save", with two checkboxes, the lower one called Default. The setting of the lower one is active, even though the checkbox itself is not displayed on the page layout (controlled by the upper one).

In the sandbox, Default was checked, in production it wasn't! I wonder if I can find the responsible person via the log that monitors configuration changes. Anyway, it works now, in our production org.